# Handle dynamic response

Tags: java, kotlin, retrofit2

How to fetch below dynamic JSON response using Retrofit2 in Kotlin/Java?
Sample JSON response where dates & currency data is dynamic

```
{
 "rates":
  {
    "2018-01-22":
     {
      "CAD":1.2476509519,
      "HKD":7.8183675137,
      "HUF":253.0026962987,
      "EUR":0.8095854922
     },
    "2018-01-09":
     {
      "CAD":1.2476509519,
      "HKD":7.8183675137,
      "HUF":253.0026962987
     },
    "2018-01-24":
     {
      "CAD":1.2476509519,
      "HKD":7.8183675137,
      "HUF":253.0026962987,
      "RUB":56.324886658,
      "KRW":1064.8720854922
     }
   }
}
```

I have created model classes like this:

```
data class GetHistoryData(
    @SerializedName("rates")
    var rates: Any,
)

data class Exchange(
    var date: String? = "",
    var exchangeCurrencyList: ArrayList<ExchangeCurrency> = ArrayList()
)


data class ExchangeCurrency(
    var exchangeCurrency: String,
    var exchangeValue: Double
)
```

I am fetching like this below, where I have iterate each JSON-object manually,

```
val jsonObject = Gson().fromJson(
            response.data!!.rates.toString(),
            JsonObject::class.java
        )

        jsonObject?.keySet()?.forEach { _ ->
            val exchangeDatesList = ArrayList<Exchange>()
            val iterator: Iterator<String> = jsonObject.keySet().iterator()
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                val dates = Exchange()
                val dateKey = iterator.next()
                dates.date = dateKey
                val currencyObject = jsonObject.getAsJsonObject(dateKey)
                val dateIterator: Iterator<String> =
                    currencyObject.keySet().iterator()
                val exchangeCurrencyList = ArrayList<ExchangeCurrency>()
                while (dateIterator.hasNext()) {

                    val currencyKey = dateIterator.next()
                    val exchangeValue = currencyObject.get(currencyKey)
                    val exchangeCurrency = ExchangeCurrency()
                    exchangeCurrency.exchangeCurrency = currencyKey
                    exchangeCurrency.exchangeValue =
                        exchangeValue.toString().toDouble()

                    exchangeCurrencyList.add(exchangeCurrency)
                }
                dates.exchangeCurrencyList = exchangeCurrencyList
                exchangeDatesList.add(dates)
```

Is there any another approach instead for above?

Comment: What is your primary criterion for "better"?  Unless you tell us your criteria, any answers are subjective ... representing the author's *opinion*.  And that makes the question off-topic.

Comment: Yes, better means is there any another way of fetching above dynamic response. In above I have iterate every single object manually

Comment: OK, so when you say *"Is there any better approach instead for above?"* ... you actually mean *"is there any other way?"* ?  If yes, please edit your Question to ask what you mean.  Because "better" and "best" are subjective.

Comment: Done pls check. Can we use Hashmap?